# Python - Pandas: extract a phrase from column into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract 2 values from one pandas dataframe column and place it into new columns. I have tried iloc and extract but i cat seem to get hang of it. can anyone help me with this.

I have a column name symbol which has following values

BANKNIFTY25JAN2436500CE

BANKNIFTY25JAN2436500PE

.

.

.

sample output

strike  type

36500   CE

36500   PE

df['type'] = df['symbol'].str.extract('([A-Z]*\s*E)')

by using this i can successfully isolate CE/PE values. unable to extract last 5 numbers from the string.

Comment: Please format your code, since like so it's difficult to understand what you need. The 5 numbers need to be in the type column as well?

Comment: read notice and provide code of input and desired output : [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the last 5 digits and the 'CE'/'PE' part from your 'symbol' column and place them into new columns, you can use the `str.extract()` method with a suitable regular expression.

Given your example, you want to extract two parts from each entry in the 'symbol' column:

1. The last 5 digits before 'CE' or 'PE' which seem to represent the strike price.
2. The 'CE' or 'PE' part which indicates the type.

Here's the regular expression we'll use:

- `(\d{5})` to match exactly 5 digits. This will capture the strike price.
- `(CE|PE)` to match and capture either 'CE' or 'PE'. This will capture the type.

You can use these patterns in `str.extract()` like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df is your DataFrame and 'symbol' is the column with the values like 'BANKNIFTY25JAN2436500CE'

# Extracting strike and type using regular expressions
df[['strike', 'type']] = df['symbol'].str.extract('(\d{5})(CE|PE)')

# This will create two new columns in df, 'strike' with the last 5 digits, and 'type' with 'CE' or 'PE'.
```

This code snippet will add two new columns to your DataFrame: one for the strike price ('strike') and one for the type ('type'), extracted from the 'symbol' column as per your requirements.